# Accept Word button on inline suggest toolbar does not work for mac. This works fine with windows 11

Tags: vscode-extensions

On vscode editor file, we trigger vscode inlincompletionItemProvider explicitly by using command editor.action.inlineSuggest.trigger.
this shows inline suggest tool bar which has two buttons **Accept** and **Accept Word** button.
On clicking, **Accept Word** button only first word gets inserted and after that toolbar disappears and there is no way to insert remaining words from the hint.
**Accept** button works fine. i.e. it  inserts entire hint/data.
Please note, With my code - **Accept Word** button functionality works fine on windows 11  but same code does not work for mac.
Please let me know how to fix this issue?
With below snippet, on triggering inline suggest - '**testing mac accept word**' gets displayed , On clicking **Accept Word** button from inline suggest toolbar (or typing command + right arrow) '**testing**'  gets inserted , after that toolbar hides so there is no way to insert remaining text (i.e.  'mac accept word')

-below is the snippet of code

```
    class inlineCompletionitemProvider implements vscode.InlineCompletionItemProvider {
    public static hint:string = "";
    public static pos:vscode.Position;
    public static range:vscode.Range;
    provideInlineCompletionItems(document: vscode.TextDocument, position: vscode.Position, context: vscode.InlineCompletionContext, token: vscode.CancellationToken): vscode.ProviderResult<vscode.InlineCompletionItem[] | vscode.InlineCompletionList> {
            if (context.triggerKind == vscode.InlineCompletionTriggerKind.Invoke)
            {
            
                let vscodeRange:vscode.Range = new vscode.Range(inlineCompletionitemProvider.pos,position);
                let item: vscode.InlineCompletionItem = new vscode.InlineCompletionItem(`${inlineCompletionitemProvider.hint}`,vscodeRange);
                return [item];
            }
            else{
            return [];
            }
            }
            }
            
- code snippet to explicit trigger inline hint provider and display them
         
private onResult = async () => {
oracleInlineCompletionitemProvider.hint = "testing mac accept word";
oracleInlineCompletionitemProvider.pos = activeTextEditor.selection.active; 
// this is cuurent cursor position.  hints would be displayed   at this position
await vscode.commands.executeCommand('editor.action.inlineSuggest.trigger');        
}
```